# iTextSharp Html Arabic Mixed Content to PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

We are in project for educational domain, where we are looking for importing Arabic content, Images (uri/base64 crypted texts), html tables.

We are facing issue while executing using HtmlWorker with Stream data. It throws error as "the document has no pages"

```
string str="html content contains arabic font texts/images";
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30))
    {
        using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,ms))
        {
           using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document))
           {
             //HTMLWorker doesn't read a string directly but instead needs a TextReader (which StringReader subclasses)
             using (var sr = new StreamReader(str))  /// We are facing issue at this juncture where it throws error.
             {
               //Parse the HTML
               htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
             }
           }

           document.Close();
           writer.Close();
           ms.Close();

           Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=First_PDF_document.pdf");
           Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help us regarding this?

Now,

I have tried with other approach:

```
 using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document))
                        {
                            using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(str))
                            {
                                using (var srt = new StreamReader(s))
                                {
                                    //Parse the HTML
                                    htmlWorker.Parse(srt); //this line throws error now.
                                }
                            }
                        }


  public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

**Error message:**

> "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: The way you're asking your question, there is no way to give an answer. Please give some sample input, your code, and preferrably also what you expect your document to look like. Also, as an iText employee I advise you to use the newest version of iText(Sharp). The HTML conversion support is much better in iText 5, especially regarding Arabic. Please experiment some with the `XMLWorker` addon, read some documentation on http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker , and I'll be happy to answer your specific and well-worded questions.

Comment: I have just edited my question with code prototype and remarks.